# Node.js route related

Tags: javascript

```
http://localhost:xxxx/home/css/styles.css
```

My CSS folder is in public directory but when I am rendering the page from:

```
/home
```

route it is changing the CSS path.

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:xxxx/home/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/Html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Comment: Your question lacks information for the community to help you. What server / environement are you using ?

Comment: You need to configure the server to serve CSS files with `Content-Type: text/css`.